# Vb.Net Moq: Intercepting parameter and set to variable

Tags: vb.net, moq

I have a mocked object and i want to assign a variable with the parameter i'm calling it with:

```
Dim myMockedObject = new Mock(Of MyObject)()

Dim catchedVariable As MyEventArgs
myMockedObject.Setup(Sub(x) x.MyMethod(Of MyEventArgs)(It.IsAny(Of MyEventArgs)))
```

I need to find a way to fill the `catchedVariable`

Was not able to figure out a way to use an out parameter(Method is ByVal and don't want to change it just for testing).

Tried Moq method like `CallBack` but no succes there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with the Callback:

```
_args As MyEventArgs
myMockedObject.Setup(Sub(x) x.MyMethod(Of MyEventArgs)(It.IsAny(Of MyEventArgs)())).Callback(Sub(x As MyEventArgs) _args = x)
```